# confparse says IP address is not found as file or directory

Tags: python

This is the what I'm trying to accomplish with my code:

```
properties( IPADDR='192.168.0.1', NETMASK='255.255.255.0' ).apply_to( '/path/to/ifcfg-eth0' )
```

However, it's stating that the IP address is not found as file or directory.  But from the docs we can see that is the proper format.

SEE: http://code.google.com/p/confparse/

CODE BELOW:

```
def writestaticConf(nic, ipa, netm):
    """ Write conf file """
    whichnic = '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-' + nic
    print whichnic
    ip = "IPADDR=" + ipa
    mask = "NETMASK=" + netm
    print ip + " " + mask
    properties(ip, mask).apply_to(whichnic)
```

TRACEBACK BELOW

```
In [45]: writestaticConf('eth0','192.168.0.1', '255.255.255.0')
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
IPADDR=192.168.0.1 NETMASK=255.255.255.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-00917222fac3> in <module>()
----> 1 writestaticConf('eth0','192.168.0.1', '255.255.255.0')

<ipython-input-44-7af6f7537082> in writestaticConf(nic, ipa, netm)
      6     mask = "NETMASK=" + netm
      7     print ip + " " + mask
----> 8     properties(ip, mask).apply_to(whichnic)
      9     #w.apply_to(whichnic)

/root/.virtualenvs/teknasportal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confparse-1.0a1-py2.7.egg/confparse.py in __init__(self, _fileordict, _order, **kwargs)
    123         if isinstance( _fileordict, str ) or isinstance( _fileordict, list):
    124             self.template=_fileordict
--> 125             self.read( _fileordict )
    126 
    127         elif hasattr( _fileordict, '__setitem__' ):

/root/.virtualenvs/teknasportal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confparse-1.0a1-py2.7.egg/confparse.py in read(self, filenames)
    309 
    310         if isinstance(filenames, basestring):
--> 311             self._read( file(filenames), filenames)
    312             self.template=filenames
    313 

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IPADDR=192.168.0.1'
```

Comment: There is a valid reason why you cannot use 'problem' in question titles. Don't subvert the filter by misspelling it please, and instead come up with a better title.

Comment: You'd be surprised at home many do do just that. If you honestly misspelled 'problem' then you have my apologies. Yet *every* question here is *because* someone has a problem, so saying you have a problem is stating the obvious. snowandotherjoys' edit made your title far more useful to anyone looking at the question list. For next time take into account we get 1000s of questions per day here, and having to deal with a disregard for minimal standards from many question askers day in, day out wears out the welcome.

Comment: I didn't say I had a problem. I was asking if there was a problem with the package. ie bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
properties('IPADDR=192.168.0.1', 'NETMASK=255.255.255.0')
```

is not the same as

```
properties(IPADDR='192.168.0.1', NETMASK='255.255.255.0')
```

If you want to use a keyword argument, use a keyword argument! Don't prepend `'IPADDR='` to the string itself.

```
properties(IPADDR=ip, NETMASK=mask)
```

Comment: You are correct.  No need to get !, I'm new to programming. But thanks for you help.